# Passing multiple arbitrary parameters to a tool (chain used as a tool)

Tags: python, agent, langchain

I'm building an agent to interact with neo4j with a custom chain (I'm aware of the chains already implemented for this case), my problem comes when I try to pass multiple arbitrary arguments to my tool. What i want to know is how can I propagate arguments from the creation of the agent / tool, and how to propagate arguments thorugh the execution of the AgentExecutor. Here is my code so far.

I have a chain that I use as a tool:

```
class LLMCypherGraphChain(Chain, BaseModel):
    input_key: List[str] = ["question", "content_type"]
```

Then I create my AgentExecutor and use the initialize_agent method, I instantiate the class previously defined and use the run method as a function to execute.

```
class GraphAgent(AgentExecutor):
@classmethod
    def initialize(cls,...)
        cypher_tool = LLMCypherGraphChain(
            llm=llm,
            input_key=["question", "content_type"],
            graph=graph,
            verbose=verbose,
            memory=readonlymemory
        )

        # Load the tool configs that are needed.
        tools = [
            Tool(
                name="Cypher search",
                func=cypher_tool.run,
                description="""
                Utilize this tool to search within a database, specifically designed to answer x questions.
                This specialized tool offers streamlined search capabilities to help you find the movie information you need with ease.
                Input should be full question.""",  # noqa
            )
        ]

        agent_chain = initialize_agent(
            tools,
            llm,
            agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
            verbose=verbose,
            memory=memory,
            return_intermediate_steps=True
        )
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().run(*args, **kwargs)
```

So at this point I only need to instantiate the agent and run it.

```
self.agent_executor = GraphAgent.initialize(
           ...
        )

res = self.agent_executor({"question": "my question",
                           "input": "my question",
                           "random_param": "my other param"})
```

So the problem is that I have this agent stored in a variable to avoid recreating it, that means self.agent_executor is only initialized once but then I want to be able to propagate the question and random_param to my tool.

I have seen some posts about passing parameters to tools but none of them actualy solved this problem. I am not sure if using agent_kwargs in the initialize_agent would be a solution (I'm not quite sure how that propagates to the tools) but that only would happen once, when the instantiation is done.

Right now I'm getting this error, so I am not understanding how arguments are propagated:

```
ERROR:root:A single string input was passed in, but this chain expects multiple inputs ({'question', 'content_type'}). When a chain expects multiple inputs, please call it by passing in a dictionary, eg `chain({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})`
```

**Update 1: A little bit more of context**
The problem is that the LLMChain is generating the input for the run method of my LLMCypherGraphChain. In the "plan" method defined by:

```
    def plan(
        self,
        intermediate_steps: List[Tuple[AgentAction, str]],
        callbacks: Callbacks = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> Union[AgentAction, AgentFinish]:
        """Given input, decided what to do.

        Args:
            intermediate_steps: Steps the LLM has taken to date,
                along with observations
            callbacks: Callbacks to run.
            **kwargs: User inputs.

        Returns:
            Action specifying what tool to use.
        """
        full_inputs = self.get_full_inputs(intermediate_steps, **kwargs)
        full_output = self.llm_chain.predict(callbacks=callbacks, **full_inputs)
        return self.output_parser.parse(full_output)
```

the prediction of the llm is:

````
'Action:\n```\n{\n  "action": "Cypher search",\n  "action_input": "Who directed the green mile?"\n}\n```\n'
````

I'm still unable to identify how can i modify this action_input to adapt it to the input expected by the run method of my chan which is a Dict with a certain format. And of course the dictionary is supposed contain parameters not generated by the LLM but rather propagated through the run method

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass multiple arguments, you have to use [StructuredTool.html](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/tools/langchain.tools.base.StructuredTool.html)

> Tool that can operate on any number of inputs.

```
from langchain.tools import StructuredTool

your_tool=StructuredTool.from_function(
           name="Cypher search",
                func=cypher_tool.run,
                description="""
                Utilize this tool to search within a database, specifically designed to answer x questions.
                This specialized tool offers streamlined search capabilities to help you find the movie information you need with ease.
                Input should be full question.""",  # noqa
)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a solution since the arguments I want to pass are not llm generated but rather context parameters. For example let's say I want to provide some confidential info to my tool, this is not generated by the llm.

Comment: `Tool` accepts only one argument.